# Is there any solution of the error of sorting user input array using STL?

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax-error

My code is:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Interval
{
    int init,last;
};
bool compare(Interval a,Interval b)
{
    return (a.init < b.init);
}

int main()
{
        int t,i,j;
        int a[1000];
        cin >> t;
        for( j=0;j<t;++j){
          for(i=0;i<t;i++)
          {
               cin >> a[i];        
          }   
       } 
       sort(a,a+t,compare);
       for( j=0;j<t;++j)
       for(i=0;i<t;i++) 
       {
          cout<<a[i]<<" ";

       }
       cout<<"\n";
       return 0;
}
```

What is the solution of the below line?

```
sort(a,a+t,compare);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code and what you have tried and why it went wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to sort an array of integers, but your `compare` function does not compare integers.

Comment: Fantastic Mr Fox thanks for remembering me. The problem may be at this Line return (a.init < b.init); I couldn't get it.

Comment: Yeah @john ,exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
bool compare(Interval a,Interval b)
{
    return (a.init < b.init);
}
```

`compare` compares `Interval` objects

But

```
    int a[1000];
    sort(a,a+t,compare);
```

you are trying to sort an `int` array.

Either sort an `int` array or an `Interval` array, but be consistent. The `compare` function must match the array that you are sorting.

Comment: actually if `Interval` had a conversion from `int` it would be fine, but constructing an interval from a single `int` doesnt really make sense

Comment: Or just don't use the predicate for the sort, since `operator<` exists for `int` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to sort `int a[1000];` which is an `int` array, not an `Interval` array. If this is really your intention, then you do not need the predicate (`compare` function) for sort. You can simply use the default `operator<` that is provided for `int`. That means you code could just be:

```
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + t);
```

Comment: That means I also don't need to use structure?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but you don't really use the structure at the moment